# Checking model state in view ASP.MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm building my own simple jQuery popup for my application. I applied the jQuery script to be fired when the model is not null but it keeps firing errors everytime it starts up finding that the model object is has no reference at all. How do we properly check if the model is not null without applying a reference object set bool = true in every controller

TempData is used for passing notification messages to another controller and then using a ViewModel to pass to a ViewBag.

```
@model ViewModel

@if(Model.Notify.ShowMessage == true) // ERROR HERE.
{

// jQuery Script comes here.

<div class="PopupMsgHolder"></div>
}
```

Update: Added the Error:

This is the error: I know the error can be fixed by simply adding the reference to the object on my controller. But my question are there other alternatives/proper procedures in checking the view that if(Model.Notify.Message == true). At first loading the web application the value is undefined, That object is only set true from another controller(LoginController) after sucessfully authenticating the user.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> ```
> Line 63: 
> Line 64: 
> Line 65: @if(Model.Notify.ShowMessage == true)
> Line 66: {
> Line 67:     <script>
> ```

Comment: Anything your LoginController does is lost on the next page request. You need to do it each time a page is requested (therefore in all controllers). Inherit all your controllers from a single base controller and have it do any security checks in an `OnActionExecuting` override in the base controller.

Comment: You could check the `Model` and all its properties for `null`: `@if (Model != null && Model.Notify != null &&  Model.Notify.ShowMessage != null && Model.Notify.ShowMessage == true) {...}`. Paranoia is good sometimes...